# Borrar archivos rtf guardados en el servidor

Tags: asp, rtf

Amigos, por favor, me podrían orientar con el siguiente problema, a través de un botón genero un archivo rtf con datos que traigo desde base de datos (sqlserver), hasta aqui todo funciona, pero si yo actualizo un dato por base de datos y vuelvo a generar el archivo rtf no me refresca la información, me toma el primer archivo generado, no se como hacer para que pueda eliminarse y volver a bajar el archivo. Mi código es le siguiente

```
Strconn = CadenaConexion
Set Conn = Server.Createobject("adodb.connection")
Conn.open StrConn

ID = Request.QueryString("ID")

sSQL="SELECT * FROM VISTA_DATOS WHERE ID='" & ID & "'"
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)

Archivo = "contratos/" & ID & "_modificacion.rtf"

archivooriginal= Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "documentacion/documento.rtf" 
archivonuevo= request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & Archivo
Set original = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
Set nuevo = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
Set fich = original.OpenTextFile(archivooriginal) 
texto_fichero = fich.readAll() 
fich.Close()


texto_fichero = Replace(texto_fichero,"@ID",ID)
texto_fichero = Replace(texto_fichero,"@FECHA",FECHA)

Set fich = nuevo.CreateTextFile(archivonuevo) 
fich.Write(texto_fichero) 
fich.Close()
Response.Redirect(Archivo)
```

El problema es que no se como puedo eliminar el primer registro que generé, porque lo que necesito, es por cada vez que yo modifico la base de datos me genere un nuevo archivo y me eliminé el anterior.

Por fis, ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que indicarle al crear el archivo que es en modo de [sobreescritura](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_createtextfile_folder.asp) mediante el true como parámetro de la función `CreateTextFile`.

```
Set fich = nuevo.CreateTextFile(archivonuevo, true)
```

sustituyendo la línea que tenías (cuarta por abajo)

```
Set fich = nuevo.CreateTextFile(archivonuevo)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero disculpa lo ignorante de mi pregunta, donde debo poner esa linea, o más bien debo jugar con esa linea?

Comment: He editado la respuesta, simplemente debes sustituir la que ya tienes por la nueva (cuarta línea por abajo).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me a resultado, pero tengo un inconveniente, si apreto el que me descargo, sigo sin actualizar los datos, pero si me voy a la carpeta donde los guardo que es contratos, ahi si me lo modifica, que puede ser?

Comment: Pues no te sabría decir, pero el archivo que guardas es "archivonuevo" y rediriges a "archivo", cambia la última línea por `Response.Redirect(archivonuevo)`

Comment: Gracias, pero al redireccionar como me dices tu, la página se cae y me dice que no existe :'(

Comment: El problema es que es una rruta física, no lógica del servidor http. Puede que sea un problema de caché o bien que lo puedas solucionar con esto:
`Response.Redirect("contratos\" & ID & "_modificacion.rtf")`

Comment: Gracias, muchas gracias